# Threejs textureLoader - scaling and mapping to mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader, texture-mapping

I have a cube that I'm trying to map an image onto. I'm loading the image with a loading Manager. I'm wondering why the material.map is returning as undefined, also wondering if maybe I have a scaling issue. The original image is 512x512. The boxes are 20x20x20.

I left out all the code about camera, renderer, etc., but I attempted to include it all in the code snippet/interactive part below.

```
var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

loadingManager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {

  //Loading percentage
  console.log(loaded / total * 100 + '%');

}

//Signify loading done
loadingManager.onLoad = function () {

  //Start the animation when the models are done loading
  animate();
}

function init() {

  //create a loader
  var loader2 = new THREE.TextureLoader(loadingManager);

  //load the texture, and when it's done, push it into a material
  loader2.load("../img/leo.jpg", function (texture) {

    //do I need to do this?
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    texture.repeat.set(boxSize, boxSize)

    //why is this texture not coming through?
    console.log(texture)

    //does not work:
    material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });


  })

  var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 30)
  var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xb7b7b7
  })
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material1)
  scene.add(mesh)

}

// This works, so I know the image path is correct
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = '../img/leo.jpg';
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(img);
```

The value of texture from the console log is this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add a breakpoint  when defining `material1`? What's the value of `texture` at that line? Debugging is crucial when you don't have an expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you @Marcs - i've added a screengrab of the console log. And I added a debugger and checked it. Any thoughts, given that the image inside the material is coming up null?

Comment: Don't worry about the snippet it is not convenient if you need external libraries, you can remove it, the image too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to the fact that you are associating the material outside the callback of the `load` function of your loader, you have to do that inside the callback.

From the documentation for [TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader):

- `onLoad` - Will be called when load completes.

You have to do as follow:

```
loader2.load("../img/leo.jpg", function(texture) {
      texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
      texture.repeat.set( boxSize,boxSize )
      //why is this texture 1 not coming through?
      console.log(texture)

      //neither of these work:
      var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30,30,30);
      material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture,side: THREE.DoubleSide });

      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material1);

        // animation loop
       function animate() {

         requestAnimationFrame( animate );

         render();

        // update stats
        stats.update();
      }

      ...
});
```

To make this more readable and avoid a callback nightmare do something like this:

```
function myInit(texture) {
  ...
}

loader2.load("../img/leo.jpg", myInit);
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcs! Yes, my code was too messy I guess. This completely saved it! I was so stuck, thank you again for taking the time.

Comment: Happy to help @EJW. Always remember that in Javascript you have to consider callbacks when loading or accessing external resources.